# how to display data from different tables column into one table column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I am trying to get data in one table's column from different tables (with same name) column in one database in SQL2008.

I created one table using different tables primary key column name (e.g.- My new table looks like

Location, Customer, Service, Channel, Monthlyperiod.....those tables are already created. I am trying to get each tables column value in other table.(e.g. - existing Lacation table column value in new location table column.

Please help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: can you add the scheme of your tables?

Comment: MySQL is not sql server 2008. Pick one.

Comment: Hello Friends..Thank you for your prompt response.. sorry that my question was not clear enough. I created one table with 4 different columns. (location, customer, service and channel). I am trying to display records under those columns from difeerent tables specific colums (I have location, customer, service and channel tables in database.) lets say from location table, i need to pick location ID and display that into my new table's location column.. I am sorry as i am new to SQL. Thank you.

Comment: @user1706420, your description is very difficult to follow.  Please update your question with the SQL definitions of each table you are working with, e.g. `create table Service (ServiceID int ...)`.  Sample data and an expected output would be extremely helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  In sql server   You  have to  do this  stuff with using  alias names  like example from ur query

```
SELECT     Location =C.Location
           ,Customer =C.Customer
           ,Service =C.Service
           ,Location2=(SELECT B.Location FROM Table2 B  where     B.customerid=C.customerid)
    FROM   Customer C --  Use alais names
```

Comment: Hello Kumar, Thank you for your help. I think i found solution with following query.......SELECT L.LocationCode, L.LocationName, C.CustomerCode, M.MaterialCode, CO.Date, SUM(CO.Amount) FROM CustomerOrderHistory (NOLOCK) CO, Material (NOLOCK) M, Customer (NOLOCK) C, Location (NOLOCK) L WHERE CO.MaterialID = M.MaterialID AND CO.CustomerID = C.CustomerID AND CO.LocationID = L.LocationID GROUP BY L.LocationCode, L.LocationName, C.CustomerCode, M.MaterialCode, CO.Date

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear but looks like you want to insert the content of one table into another with the same schema.

Let's suppose your table has three columns Location Customer and Service and the tables with identical schema are Customer and Customer1, then inserting all rows of the first table into the second will be done like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customer1
SELECT     Location, Customer, Service
FROM         Customer
```

Comment: Hello Dennis...Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: Hello Dennis..Thank you for your prompt response.. sorry that my question was not clear enough. I created one table with 4 different columns. (location, customer, service and channel). I am trying to display records under those columns from difeerent tables (I have location, customer, service and channel tables in database.) lets say from location table, i need to pick location ID and display that into my new table's location column.. I am sorry as i am new to SQL. Thank you.

Comment: There is two problems in your explanation: 

1) You say you need to _display_, but you also saying that you already created a _table_ with 4 columns. You need table only if you need to store something. To display something combining data from 4 tables you do not need to create table - you can just use a SELECT statement.

Comment: 2) When you need to display data combining columns from different tables you usually use a JOIN in your SELECT statement. Problem is that it is not enough to just say: "combine columns with these names" you also need to specify the rules how to combine these columns. If for example your Customer table contains columns CustomerName, LocationID and ServiceID; your Location table contains  columns LocationID, LocationName; and your Service table contains ServiceID, ServiceName, then your can display all columns with the following SELECT:

Comment: SELECT     C.CustomerName, L.LocationName, S.ServiceName
FROM         Customer AS C LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Location AS L ON C.LocationID = L.LocationID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Service AS S ON C.ServiceID = S.ServiceID

Comment: Thanks Dennis..I think i found solution with following qury:..........SELECT L.LocationCode, L.LocationName, C.CustomerCode, M.MaterialCode, CO.Date, SUM(CO.Amount)
   FROM CustomerOrderHistory (NOLOCK) CO,
            Material (NOLOCK) M,
            Customer (NOLOCK) C,
            Location (NOLOCK) L
  WHERE CO.MaterialID = M.MaterialID
    AND CO.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
    AND CO.LocationID = L.LocationID
GROUP BY L.LocationCode, L.LocationName, C.CustomerCode, M.MaterialCode, CO.Date